# Is the following argument an instance of modus tollens?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If anything is appearance it is known conditionally;
We know we act unconditionally; Therefore, action cannot be appearance.

> If P, then Q.  Not Q. Therefore, not P.

Valid?

If we change the second premise to "We know we *can* act unconditionally", does that not change the argument from a deductive to an inductive one?

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Sentences like "If anything is appearance it is known conditionally" really aren't mathematical in nature.  In particular, it is not clear what this might have to do with "action" which doesn't even appear in your assumption.

Comment: i do not follow the content so well, either...but the form seems fairly simple...although I am not quite sure!

Comment: Maybe this should be on philosophy stack exchange?

Comment: The argument *is* an appeal to modus tollens.  I'm not sure that it is valid though.  (I  think the "know" and "condition" in "we know we act unconditionally" are completely different things than the "known" and "condition" of "If anything is appearance it is known conditionally".  But perhaps this is simply an atrocious translation.  I doubt this originated in English).  But it follows (validly or not) the format of modus tollens.

Comment: Something following the form of modus tollens doesn't need to be valid.  For example "All animals are alive"  "My cat is dead" therefore "My cat is not an animal" is not a valid argument.  But the error is not in the logical form.  It's in abusing the ambiguity of the statements (which are all valid in most but not all circumstances; the argument was artificially constructed to abuse the few circumstances they do not agree)

Comment: I think: In the hypothesis "If anything is appearance it is known conditionally" the "conditionally" refers to the knowledge.  In the " We know we act unconditionally" the "(un)conditionally" refers to the action, not the knowledge (and the knowledge refers to us knowing our behaviors; not our specific actions).  Therefore I do not think the argument if valid.... Not to mention I haven't got the flukiest flume of what the goobity-flipping heck they are talking about!

Comment: it is tough.  Basically it has to do with non-observational knowledge.  So all our knowledge is of appearances, except for that internal knowledge or awareness of the very fact that we are acting.  We know that immediately/directly, without having to observe anything.

Comment: "All animals are alive" "My cat is dead" therefore "My cat is not an animal" is not a valid argument. --  would you say this is valid, but not sound, since the premises are clearly false?

Comment: I don't think the premises *are* false.  I think they are true.  But I think their meaning is misapplied. Much as I think the meanings of "known" and "conditionally" are misapplied in the second sentence.  FWIW I think my animal argument is more akin to the Anselm argument of the existence of God.  God is the most perfect of beings, A non-existent being is less than perfect, ergo God exists. (also modus tollens) ["God is most perfect" *is* true **as a definition** but misapplied as **a fact** which is isn't.]